# php code: count the number of rows in oracle sql

Tags: php, oracle, authentication

I try to write a logIn.php. But the number of rows always returns 0. Thanks for your help!

```
       $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM users WHERE '.password.' = '.$password.' AND '.name.' = '.$username.'";
       $stid = oci_parse($dbh, $sql);  
       oci_execute($stid);  

       oci_fetch_all($stid, $result);
       $row = $result['C'][0];
       echo $row;
```

Comment: pls use $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM users WHERE password = '{$password}' AND name = '{$username}'"; may be your sql having  an error so it returning always 0. also use error handling.

Comment: check what the entire result is (print_r($result);)